# In python 2, how to write a function that prints to stdout by default and to an argument stream otherwise?

Tags: python, io, stream

I'm trying to write a function that prints a data structure to a stream if such a stream is given as an argument, otherwise it prints it to stdout. That, is, I would like to write something like the following:

```
def printStructure(struct, stream = stdout):
  for e in struct.element:
    print >> stream, struct
```

So that if the second argument is not given, the function prints on screen, and prints to `stream` otherwise. Does the stdout stream have a name in python? Are there some alternatives to this?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you are looking for `sys.stdout` (`import sys`)

Comment: and something of this sort: `print("foo", *objs, file=sys.stderr)`, for example. (python 3, import print_function)

Comment: Yes I was! thanks fredtantini. Would you reckon this is a god way of achieving this?

Comment: In the unix world, you usually print everything to stdout, and redirect your program if you need a file: `python foo.py > baz`.

Comment: Thanks georg, but I need to call that function from inside a python program, not from the command line. I might want sometimes to print stuff to a file, and sometimes to print the same stuff to another, or to stdout, so that's why I needd that.

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3 ?

Comment: Python 2, thanks for asking @JoelCornett

Comment: @fredtantini you provided me with the exact answer I was looking for, so if you want to write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Code and simple demo is here:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys


def printStructure(struct, stream=sys.stdout):
    if stream != sys.stdout:
        sys.stdout = stream
        print struct
    else:
        print struct

if __name__ == "__main__":
    printStructure("Print to file: 0", open('out.log', 'w'))
    printStructure("Print to console: 1")
    printStructure("Print to file: 1", open('out.log', 'aw'))
    printStructure("Print to file: 2", open('out.log', 'aw'))
    printStructure("Print to console: 2")
```

Comment: I don't think this does what you want

Comment: I misspoke. It *does* do what you want, but the change is permanent. After assignment of stdout, *all* future print statements will be directed to the value of `stream`.

Comment: Additionally, there is no semantic difference between what you did and the simpler: `stream = sys.stdout; print struct`

Answer (score 0):

The `print()` function already has this functionality built in.

### Python 3

```
stream = open("myfile.txt", "w")
print("Some text", out=stream) # prints "Some text" to myfile.txt

print("Some text") # prints "Some text" to stdout
```

### Python 2

For Python 2, in order to enable the print function, you need to add the following line to the top of your script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

After that, the steps are the same

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want, you can use [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdout). It's a file object corresponding to the interpreter’s standard output streams and is used for the output of print.
So in the same way you do

```
print >> stream, struct
```

to print to a file, you can just do:

```
print >> sys.stdout, struct
```

to print to stdout.

You could also "redirect" temporarily `sys.stdout` to a file:

```
>>> import sys
>>> oldSysStdout = sys.stdout #store original stdout object for later
>>> sys.stdout = open('someFile.log','w') #redirect all prints to this log file
>>> print "test1" #nothing is printed at the screen
>>> sys.stdout.close()
>>> sys.stdout=oldSysStdout 
>>> print "test2"
test2 #normal printing
>>>
~$ cat someFile.log
test1
```

Note that in python3.x or with `from __future__ import print_function`, the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) function has an argument, which by default is `sys.stdout`:

```
 print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)
```